# MongoDB - accessing cursor with spaces in keys

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'v collection with keys containing spaces and I'v no idea how to access it from js script . For example:

```
c = db.collection.find()
    while(c.hasNext()) {
    print(c.next().'my key with spaces');
}
```

Doesn't work. How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the bracket notation `[]` if you *keys* are not a valid identifier (e.g contains spaces) instead of dot `.`  notations to access your objects properties or documents fields. But generally speaking you should avoid using such identifier.

```
c = db.collection.find()
    while(c.hasNext()) {
    print(c.next()['my key with spaces']);
}
```

Also you can use the `.forEach` method instead of a *while loop*

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(document) {
    print(document['my key with spaces']);
}
```

Or even better using an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) new in ECMAScript 6

```
db.collection.find().forEach(document => print(document['my key with spaces']))
```

Comment: Detailed documentation on object literal syntax: [MDN - Object Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)